# Spring 6 Upgrade | CSS and JS files not loading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Recently we upgraded our project to Spring version 6.0.0. After that website assets did not load on website anymore.

We observed below issue:

CSS path having "system" is not loading: ** system/assets/css/main.css** => Not Working

If we use "resources" in path as ** resources/assets/css/main.css** ,  The css file starts loading on the website.

Where do we need to make any configuration changes to make the "system" path of CSS continue working? We cannot use "resources" path for our css files.

Tried below code:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/system/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will cause commotion, but the elements of your usage will obviously be giving you a greater chance to figure out if you're willing to look at both place and scope of your files. For this registry, your updated files need configuration to be upheld. If you didn't work the new configurations to their limits of completion to coordinate with your site, then you'll definitely need to redistribute your old sources. But, before you think that perhaps you made a mistaken in going this way, try a very much simpler framework for adding, responsive data.

```
<pipe class-attr="attribute1:value;attribute2:value;" attribution="class-to-add-attributes"></pipes>
```

You would point that at your `<style>` tag and it would fill in the attributes needed. Obviously everything here can be done dynamically. The `<pipe>` tag has a "onLoad" EventListener. If you want to change them with a click, a simple way is to use that same inner attribution, and use it as a `<dyn>` tag which just stands for "responsive" UI.

PipesJS can be found on github in the wise-penny/pipes repository. Hope this at least gives a lead.